# Deep Reinforcement Learning behaviour when the next state is same as the prev_state for the same episode

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I have a problem where when we start an episode we are in a State which is randomly chosen out of N discreet states(N is a number). An action A (continuous action space) is taken and a reward R is received. However, the next state doesn't change. Thus the state transition looks like -> (S, A, R, S). I was wondering if anyone has ever tried this problem with DDPG(because of continuous action space). Is it even a RL problem?

Any idea what would the behaviour be if we tried to run such a problem(where state doesn't change upon taking an action) with DDPG?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems incomplete. Is it happenening at every step? Or just a few of them which you were able to notice. If it is the latter then yes, the previous state and next state can be similar. It really depends on the configuration of the environment. In DDPG, depending on the continous action, it is quite possible for it to stay in the same state depending on what happens when the agent takes a 'step' inside the environment.

Comment: Is is happening for every step. Whatever action you take, the state doesn't change

Comment: I don't have the code. It's a conceptual question for now. Its like taking a standard ddpg problem and applying a specific constraint that changes the problem a bit. So, I wanna know how it changes the algorithm used.